# Updating datafram columns with same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, dfA: containing data and dfB: other is 1-row dataframe which contains header information. I need to update dfB and add all the columns that dfB has. The value of each row of those appended column should has the exact row from dfB (duplicates)

dfA:

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a0 | b0 | c0 |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |

dfB:

| colD | colE | colF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d0 | e0 | f0 |

the desired output should look like

| colA | colB | colC | colC | colD | colE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a0 | b0 | c0 | **d0** | **e0** | **f0** |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | **d0** | e0 | **f0** |

I have tried

> pd.concat([df,header_df],axis=1,join='outer')
> but it only appends to the first row and leave the n other rows with null values like this:

| colA | colB | colC | colC | colD | colE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a0 | b0 | c0 | **d0** | **e0** | **f0** |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | null | null | null |

Comment: you can do a ffill() on ColC, ColD, ColE after you concat. Alternate, you can modify dfB to be of same length as dfA by using repeat

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df,header_df],axis=1).ffill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame's `fillna` method after your `concat` step - to "forward fill" the values from the first row into all the subsequent rows

```
df = pd.concat([df,header_df],axis=1,join='outer')
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```